# How to extract file location (that has a space) from command line argument in batch script

Tags: batch-file

My batch file accepts 4 arguments:
mybatch.bat -name=path leading to a file -type=some predefined enum

i then pass it to another batch file to check if both values are given.

My question is when i receive path containing a space how do i extract the location of the file. It might or might not contain space.

I know how to handle without space.

### Contents of main bat file

```
set arg1=%~1
set arg2=%~2
set arg3=%~3
set arg4=%~4
set name=
set sType=

if "%*" == "" (
goto Help 
)

call parse.bat
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
goto error
) else if %errorlevel% equ 2 (
goto Help 
)
set file=%name%
FOR %%i IN ("%file%") DO (
set filedrive=%%~di
set filepath=%%~pi
set filename=%%~ni
)
set fileLoc=%filedrive%%filepath%
set name=%filename%
```

### Contents of parse.bat

```
if defined arg5 echo "invalid argument" & goto :error

if /I %arg1% equ -help (
exit /b 2
) else if /I %arg1% equ -h (
exit /b 2
)

if /I %arg1% equ -name (
    set name=!arg2!
) else if /I %arg1% equ -sType (
    set sType=%arg2%
) else (
    goto :error
)

if not defined arg3 goto :chkparam
if /I %arg3% equ -name (
    set name=%arg4%
) else if /I %arg3% equ -sType (
    set sType=%arg4%
) else (
    goto :error 
)
```

### The moment i enter a path which has space in between it says :

```
main.bat -name="c:\tmp\New folder\file2.txt" -stype=other
folder\file2.txt" -stype=other" was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: You have to put quotes around such paths: `main.bat -name="c:\tmp\New folder\file2.txt" -stype="other
folder\file2.txt"`

Comment: @aschipfl: yes i am aware of that. When i drag and drop the file into cmd prompt it automatically adds " " surrounding the argument when there is a space. My question is how can i set that argument value to my variable?

like say :
set arg2=%~1 
or "arg2=%~1"

Tried both but no luck so far.

Comment: The best way to assign variables is `set "VAR=Value"`. Your problem however is something else, I believe. Anyway, why do you use delayed expansion once for `!arg2!`? I would not do `if "%*"==""` but `if "%~1"==""`, because `%*` is the whole list of arguments potentially including quotes, but `%~1` should (usually) not include quotes, and if `%~1` is empty there is also no other argument (unless you provided `""` as the first argument, but that would not make sense anyway). Alternatively you could do `set "ARGS=%*"` and then `if not defined ARGS` to be more reliable...